# OO PHP Array values are lost or missing

Tags: php, html, arrays, scope

I'm relatively new to OO PHP, and frankly PHP in general.  I have a class that I assign the array values in the constructor.  However, when I access the array later, it is telling me that the array is null.  Any ideas how this is going out of scope?

```
class SentenceContentContainer {
    public $strSentence; //theSentence entered
    public $arrayOfWords = []; //words in the sentence
    private $num_words_in_sentence; 

    function __construct($strSentence)
    {
        $this->strSentence = $strSentence;
        $arrayOfWords = explode(" ", $strSentence); //get the array of words in the string
        $num_words_in_sentence = count($arrayOfWords); //count elements in the sentence
    }

    function sortHighestLetterRepeaterOfSentence()
    {
        usort($arrayOfWords, "compare"); //says parameter 1 is null
    }
...
}
```

This is accessed from:

```
<html>
<head><title>PHP Code</title></head>
<body>
<?php

     include "classes.php";

     //process the data input
     $post_string = implode("",$_POST); //change post array to string
     // instantiate 1 of 2 objects
     $sentenceCC = new SentenceContentContainer($post_string);

     call_user_method("sortHighestLetterRepeaterOfSentence",$sentenceCC);
     ?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I tried adding this->arrayOfWords in the Sentence contructor, it said it was a syntax issue.

I wonder if the issue is that somehow it's running the call_user_method even though I haven't hit submit yet in the form, after entering the sentence?  I wouldn't think it would have gotten there yet?

Added:  When I invoke the script in the browser, before I hit submit in the form, is when I see the warning message.
Added Also:  Maybe I need to check that $arrayOfWords is not null or something in sortHighestLetterRepeaterOfSentence?  I tried adding a check for null, but It's saying Undefined variable arrayOfWords where I test it for != null. I was also considering [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), but it's unclear that this would fix it.

Comment: Why not `$sentenceCC->sortHighestLetterRepeaterOfSentence()`? And yes, `$this` is reqired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$arrayOfWords` is a variable that only exists inside the `__construct` function.

`$this->arrayOfWords` is a *private* class variable that exists in any method of the class and has a different value per-instance.

P.S. Why are you using `call_user_method`?  This function is *deprecated* (and I think removed in PHP 7).  Just a quick note, if you saw that in a tutorial, you should consider a new tutorial as that one's gonna be outdated.

You can just do:

```
$sentenceCC->sortHighestLetterRepeaterOfSentence()
```

If you must, you can use `call_user_func` instead:

```
call_user_func([$sentenceCC, 'sortHighestLetterRepeaterOfSentence']);
```

Comment: Are you saying that if I want to add to arrayOfWords in the constructor and use it in other functions later that I need to assign it using $this->arrayOfWords?  That's not clear to me.

Comment: @Michele: Yes.  You need to use `$this->arrayOfWords` in every method of the class, including the constructor.  In the constructor, you can set its value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this code will execute even if form is not submitted.

I think your should check $_POST variable and allow to run your code only

> if (count( $_POST ))